# DIVI, trying to get reference to mobile menu using JS - undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onload, divi, domcontentloaded

#### The Problem

I'm using the DIVI theme and am simply attempting to get a reference to the mobile menu's ul element (this has a class of 'et_mobile_menu'). Up until now I've not had any issues getting references in javascript, but this particular one always seems to be undefined/null.

#### What I've attempted

I tried it in a setTimeout and it worked (it found the element with no problems).  So, I tried it using:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let el = document.querySelector('.et_mobile_menu');
});
```

This didn't work.  So I gave onload a try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let el = document.querySelector('.et_mobile_menu');
}
```

Again, this didn't work so I tried using JQuery like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let el = document.querySelector('.et_mobile_menu');
});
```

Now this did work... every time the reference was valid.

#### More Information

I'm using a simple DIVI child theme which I created, and my javascript file is being enqueued in the footer.  I've specified 'jquery' as a dependency and have tried add_actions() with different priorities. (I've also tried this with getElementsByClassName())

#### Summary

I'm curious, is there something specific with Wordpress that I'm missing or is there more I can do to pinpoint the reason the JQuery 'ready' function works here but the vanilla JS methods don't?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your browser to view the page source code from a site built with Divi, you see that the `ul.et_mobile_menu` element does not exist (`<div class="mobile_nav closed">` is empty). The `ul.et_mobile_menu` is only appended to the HTML (by Javascript) after the page loads (maybe Divi made this change recently). So, the setTimeout approach works. And the $(document).ready approach also works, probably because the event that appends `ul.et_mobile_menu` element is triggered before that.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("document ready: "+$( '.et_mobile_menu' ).length); // echos 1
    });
    
    setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("setTimeout: "+$( '.et_mobile_menu' ).length); // echos 1
    }, 1000);
    
    console.log("document not ready: "+$( '.et_mobile_menu' ).length); // echos 0
} );
```

The console outputs:

```
document not ready: 0
document ready: 1
setTimeout: 1
```